# Can anyone recommend an IDE for developing ruby/cucumber tests

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Can anyone recommend an open-source IDE other than Eclipse/Aptana studio for developing Ruby/Cucumber tests?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Most Ruby programmers don't use IDEs, usually we work with text editors like Vim/Emacs/Textmate and run tests from the command-line. That's what I'd recommend doing!

Comment: thanks robbrit, i agree but im old school I like to have access to my teams code and check in/update all in front of me. Also coming from a java background doesnt help :)

Comment: Heh I'd say that IDEs are most definitely not old school ;) Most version control programs like git, svn, cvs, etc. all have command-line interfaces to do the check-ins and updates - in fact having used both TortoiseSVN/Git/Hg and the command-line versions I can say I prefer the command-line ones at this point!

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) has built-in support for Cucumber.

Comment: Rubymine is not open-source. I have found all IDEs un-responsive at best. Although lately I have heard lots of good things about the latest Rubymine, and it doesn't cost the earth. Personally I have had good success with Vim + plugins.